# How can I calculate the RMS and Medium Voltage in a Controlled Three-phase Full-Wave Rectifier?

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier, three-phase, scr

[image: Controlled Three-phase Full-Wave Rectifier]

I want to calculate Vrms and Vmedium for the angles of 30º, 90º and 150º on the circuit above with and current source and a resistor load.
I found a variety of formulas on the internet, but them all give different answers.

What are the ultimate formulas for calculating this values? Or how can I find them?

Comment: Why not simulate the circuit to get another "viewpoint" that will be right.

Comment: I have already simulated, but the teacher is asking for theorical values

Comment: So, which formulas gave the same answer as the simulation?

Comment: Yeah, or how I can deduce them.